# print(f.read()) returning size of string

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
with open("hello.txt", "r+") as f:
    f.write("Hello Python!\n")
    print(f.read())
```

But the output is strange:

```
14
Hello Python!
```

The string 'Hello Python!' has 13 characters (maybe for some reason it's returning 13+1?)

And worse: I just tried to increase the size of the string:

```
... with open("hello.txt", "r+") as f:
...     f.write("Hello Python!!\n")
...     print(f.read())
...     
... 
15
ello Python!

>>> with open("hello.txt", "r+") as f:
...     f.write("Hello Python!!!\n")
...     print(f.read())
... 
16
llo Python!
```

Then I opened the file hello.txt and the content was

```
Hello Python!!!
llo Python!
```

I read some docs here https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html, but it's not too deep within print(file.read())... My version of Python is 3.4.3 and my OS is Linux.

Comment: Given that you've included `\n`, why does it surprise you that the count includes it?

Comment: What a shame... I just missed that... thanks @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python interactive console automatically prints the result of expressions in the output.

For example:

```
>>> 1 + 1
2
```

`f.write()` is returning the amount of characters written in the file, and the Python REPL is printing that number before your `print(f.read())` line.

This wouldn't happen in a normal script, as expressions results aren't automatically printed.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I should take in consideration the interactive aspect of the terminal. 
After your info I stopped using the interactive terminal and I'm running the code as a script to help me understand `$ python my.py`